# Is there a general relationship between definite integrals over functions involving the complete elliptic integral of the first kind and zeta values?

Tags: reference-request, analytic-number-theory, integration, riemann-zeta-function, elliptic-functions

**Background**

Let $\textbf{K}(k)$ be the complete elliptic integral of the first kind, where $k$ is its elliptic modulus [1]. Moreover, define $k' := \sqrt{1-k^{2}} $ as its complementary modulus. I've observed a number of definite integrals of this function in various sources that indicate a connection with Riemann zeta values.

These include:

1. On p. 632, entry 6.141.2 of Gradshteyn and Ryzhik's *Table of Integrals, Series, and Products* [2], we find $$\label{grad1} \int_{0}^{1}  \textbf{K}(k') dk = \frac{\pi^{2}}{4} = \frac{3}{2} \zeta(2). \tag{1} $$
2. On p. 632, entry 6.144 of [2], we also obtain $$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\textbf{K}(k) }{1+k}dk = \frac{\pi^{2}}{8} = \frac{3}{4} \zeta(2) . \tag{2} $$
3. In the answer to the following [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3112316/is-it-true-that-int-01-bigkk1-2-big2-dk-frac72-zeta3?noredirect=1&lq=1) [3] by Tieto Piezas III, user Nico Bagis confirms that $$\label{bagis} \int_{0}^{1}  \left( \textbf{K}(k^{1/2})^{2} \right) dk = \frac{7}{2} \zeta(3). \tag{3}  $$ Other similar, conjectured definite integrals are described in the question as well.
4. In the answer to GEdgar's [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3805720/elliptic-integrals-and-zeta5?noredirect=1&lq=1) [4], pisco establishes - with help from Bagis' work - that$\raise0.9ex\small \hbox{a}$ $$\int_0^1 \frac{\textbf{K}'(k)^4}{\textbf{K}(k)^2} k\;dk = \frac{31}{8} \zeta(5) . \tag{4}$$

As pointed out by Paul Enta, the identity in \eqref{bagis} is generalised for other moments of $\textbf{K}'^{2}, \textbf{E}'^{2} $ (where $\textbf{E}(k)$ is the complete elliptic integral of the second kind), $\textbf{K}'\textbf{E}', \textbf{K}^{2},$ and $\textbf{E}^{2} $ in an article by James Wan [5], where he shows these can be expressed as numbers of the form $a + b \zeta(3)$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{Q} $. Wan's paper also shows integrals of sums of products of three or four elliptic integrals can yield closed forms, like $$ \int_{0}^{1} \left(3 \textbf{E}'(k) \textbf{K}'(k) \textbf{K}(k) - \textbf{K}(k) \textbf{K}'(k)^{2} \right) dk = \frac{\pi^{3}}{8} \tag{5} $$ on p. 12. Moreover, Kirill points out in his/her answer to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395085/closed-form-for-int-0-infty-left-int-01-frac1-sqrt1-y2-sqrt1x2-y2) [6] by Vladimir Reshetnikov that $$ \int_0^1 \textbf{K}(k)^3\,dk = \frac{3}{5} \textbf{K}(1/\sqrt{2})^4 =
\frac{3\Gamma \big{(}\frac{1}{4}\big{)}^8}{1280\pi^2}. \tag{6} $$

**Questions**$\raise0.9ex\small \hbox{b}$

1. Is anything known about the evaluation of integrals of the form $$I_{m} := \int_{0}^{1} \left( \textbf{K}(k^{1/m}) \right)^{m} dk \tag{7} $$ or $$I^{'}_{m} := \int_{0}^{1} \left( \textbf{K}\big{(}(k')^{1/m}\big{)} \right)^{m} dk \tag{8} $$ for $m>2$ ? To me, these appear like natural generalizations of \eqref{grad1} and \eqref{bagis}.
2. Is there a more general theory that describes the relationship(s) between integrals of complete elliptic integrals of the first (or second) kind on the one hand, and zeta values at positive integer arguments multiplied by rational coefficients on the other hand?

**Sources**

[1] Weisstein, Eric W. "Complete Elliptic Integral of the First Kind." From MathWorld--A Wolfram Web Resource. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteEllipticIntegraloftheFirstKind.html

[2] I.S. Gradshteyn, I. M. Ryzhik. "Table of integrals, series, and products." [http://fisica.ciens.ucv.ve/~svincenz/TISPISGIMR.pdf](http://fisica.ciens.ucv.ve/%7Esvincenz/TISPISGIMR.pdf), 2007. Seventh edition.

[3] Piezas III, T., Bagis, N. "Is it true that $\int_0^1 \big(K(k^{1/2})\big)^2\,dk = \frac{7}2\zeta(3)$?" [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3112316/is-it-true-that-int-01-bigkk1-2-big2-dk-frac72-zeta3?noredirect=1&lq=1) MSE, 2019.

[4] GEdgar, pisco, "Elliptic integrals and $\zeta(5)$." [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3805720/elliptic-integrals-and-zeta5?noredirect=1&lq=1) MSE, 2020.

[5] Wan, J. "Moments of products of Elliptic Integrals" [link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.1132) ArXiv, 2011.

[6] Reshetnikov, V., Kirill, "Closed form for $\int_0^\infty\left(\int_0^1\frac1{\sqrt{1-y^2}\sqrt{1+x^2\,y^2}}\mathrm dy\right)^3\mathrm dx.$" [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395085/closed-form-for-int-0-infty-left-int-01-frac1-sqrt1-y2-sqrt1x2-y2) MSE, 2013

**Notes**

$\raise0.9ex\small\hbox{a}$ In the context of elliptic integrals, mathematicians often denote $\textbf{K}'(k) := \textbf{K}(k') $

$\raise0.9ex\small\hbox{b}$ I've also asked [these questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4510257/is-there-a-general-relationship-between-definite-integrals-over-functions-involv) over at MSE